# letsrate gem ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `average' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am really new to the letsrate gem.

I am currently going through the example on the wiki, https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate

I installed the gem, installed devise, generated a user model, and generated a restaurant model, generated a restaurants controller with a simple show method, set the route to the controller#show. The problem is with the helper method,

this is my show.html.erb template

```
friendliness <%= rating_for @restaurant, "friendliness" %>
Taste : <%= rating_for @restaurant, "taste" %>
Price : <%= rating_for @restaurant, "price" %>
```

with my restaurant.rb model like this

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  letsrate_rateable "friendliness", "price", "taste"
end
```

and my restaurants_controller.rb like this

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController

    def show
    end 
end
```

this is my error,

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `average' for nil:NilClass):
```

This average method should be a part of the gem. Is this a gem problem or my problem? Its suppose to show the average of the stars.

Comment: your variable `@restaurant` is `nil`, you have to initialize it in your show action like this: `@restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])`

Comment: @MrYoshiji I changed the method to an index method to show all restaurants. if I do `@restaurant = Restaurant.find(1)` , the stars do come out but if I do `@restaurants = Restaurant.all` and named the instance correctly in the helper methods, why am I getting the same error?